# wxwidgets getting application path

Tags: wxwidgets

My config:

- wxWidgets version: 3.0.1
- Codeblocks version: 13.12 64bit
- Compiler: gnu gcc 4.8.2
- platform/OS: Linux 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

I can't seem to use the UseAppInfo correctly. I don't want the app name in the path, just the path of the executable. I am trying this:

```
wxStandardPaths::Get().UseAppInfo(wxStandardPaths::AppInfo_None);
wxString strExe = wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath();
```

strExe contains the full path and the executable name, despite the option AppInfo_None in UseAppInfo in the line above it. I am aware that I am getting an instance from a Get() which doesn't seem to be carried over in the next line.. The doc says to use wxStandardPaths through wxStandardPaths::Get().

I did tried the following as well, which doesn't work either (surprisingly it doesn't crash and does give me the full path including app name):

```
wxStandardPaths &path = wxStandardPaths::Get();
path.UseAppInfo(wxStandardPaths::AppInfo_None);
wxString strExe = path.GetExecutablePath();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wxGetCwd()` is not guaranteed to give the path to the application. In fact, you can change that path while the application is running using `wxSetWorkingDirectory`.

The best method I have found to get the path to the application is to use `GetExecutablePath` and use `wxFileName` to remove the application name.

```
//need to include <wx/filename.h> and <wx/stdpaths.h>

wxFileName f(wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath());
wxString appPath(f.GetPath());
```

Comment: Does this work even wth a symlinked executable?

Answer (score 2):

`GetExecutablePath()` is not affected by `UseAppInfo()` because it just gives you the executable path, wherever it is. Other `wxStandardPaths` methods do honour it and you probably want to use something like `GetDataDir()` instead of `GetExecutablePath()`.

Comment: wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath(); is the closest of what I need, I just need to remove the exe name and I got the folder where the exe resides. Thanks a lot in helping to understand!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
wxString myPath(wxGetCwd());
```

Returns the path of the app folder in myPath variable.

wxString myPath is variable type wxString wxGetCwd() return path app folder.

wxString myPath(wxGetCwd()); is path for app folder sets in myPath variable

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Returns the path of the app folder in myPath variable.
wxString myPath is variable type wxString
wxGetCwd() return path app folder.

wxString myPath(wxGetCwd());
is path for app folder sets in myPath variable!

Comment: I have copied your comment to the answer.  Please do that yourself next time.  I have also up voted your answer.

Comment: Rohit, My English is not the best to explain, and the translator always commits some errors. So I try not to talk more than necessary!
Thank you for your vote!
:)

Comment: This will often work, but not always (at least on Windows; I haven't tried playing around with it on Linux)